# OneDrive for Business REST API - PUT,POST - 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, rest, sharepoint, onedrive

We've a trial version of `Microsoft azure` and are playing with the One drive for Business CRUD operations via the `REST API` from java client as per the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/files-rest-operations).

After getting the token, I'm able to list any folder, download file and get attributes of a file using `GET` successfully.

But, the operations such as `PUT`, `POST` which are required for create folder, upload file,  rename file/folder, etc are not working. I get back `"401 UnAuthorized"` error.

Error Response `json` :

```
{"error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."}}
```

I set the access token in the similar way how i set for `GET` in the `http request` and i'm using `jboss rest` easy client for accessing the rest API
Here is a code for "Creating a folder"

```
ResteasyProviderFactory factory = ResteasyProviderFactory.getInstance();   
ResteasyProviderFactory.pushContext(javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers.class,factory);
ResteasyClientBuilder resteasyClientBuilder = new             
ResteasyClientBuilder().providerFactory(factory);
ResteasyClient client = resteasyClientBuilder.build();
ResteasyWebTarget target = client.target(BASE_URL +"/getByPath('/TestFolder1')");
Invocation.Builder request = target.request();
request.header("Authorization", "Bearer " + this.token);
Response response = request.put(Entity.text(""));
```

And as per documentation, `401 UnAuthorized error` means `"Required authentication information is either missing or invalid."`

Am i missing any header that's supposed to be in the request/ Any other issue with the request?

Comment: There might be an issue with the permissions for the folders/items that you are trying to access.  Since you're able to GET files and folders, it could be possible that the permissions are set to read-only.

Comment: @Toan-Nguyen, yes you are right. It turned out to be a config in Azure Settings. I've just updated the details over [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0a971d77-49e7-4b1e-8305-ec2efa423fbf/onedrive-for-business-rest-api-putpost-401-unauthorized?forum=sharepointdevelopment&prof=required)