# Getting Unauthorised Access Error (401) while accessing default drive using One Drive Business API

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, office365, onedrive, office365api

I want to integrate one drive for business into my windows forms application in Visual Studio 2008. I have followed the link "https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/aad_oauth.htm" for registration in Azure and authentication into Office 365. I am able to get the "https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/me" url for the logged in user and also the access token for calling one drive api's. But when I call the API to get the default drive or the files present at root level in the one drive business account, I get an unauthorized access error, Error:401. I have tried all the permutations and combinations of permissions (namely, Windows Azure Active Directory,Office 365 unified API, Office 365 Management APIs, Office 365 Sharepoint Online, Office 365 Exchange Online, Windows Azure Service Management API). 
Please suggest what else could I be missing?

This person "[Not able to use One Drive API for One Drive for Business](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33038995/not-able-to-use-one-drive-api-for-one-drive-for-business)" also had the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

And I have the same problem, but it's a API bug.
I founded this on [OneDrive for Business API item/file download content 401](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32144097/onedrive-for-business-api-item-file-download-content-401/32344521#32344521).

Thanks

Comment: Hi Nerxhan, I am not even able to access the metadata of the default drive. Any suggestions on this? Thanks

Comment: And I have the same problem. We need to wait, until they fix that bug. 
Thanks