# OneDrive for busines API with Office365

Tags: php, office365, onedrive, office365api

I'm writing a library on php to communicate Office365, and now I need to communicate with OneDrive for business.

I follow all the steps from this link https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/aad_oauth.htm

When i try to connect with curl

```
GET {serviceEndPointUri}/drive
Authorization: Bearer {access_token}
```

I get:

```
[errorNumber] => 403
[error] => Request returned HTTP error 403
```

I follow exactly all the steps from documentation for access token

Any idea,

Thanks

Comment: @femi can you help me with this issue please.

Answer (score 0):

For OneDrive for business uses office 365 API (api.office.com); Here is a sample on how to read files from OneDrive for business (o365). the link you were using is the Personal OneDrive (dev.onedrive.com).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/files-rest-operations#UsetheOffice365clientlibraryGetanaccesstoken

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Mostafa, 

Thanks for you response.

I think the link https://dev.onedrive.com/auth/aad_oauth.htm tell us how to use onedrive for business. And it's work fine, only on last step when I make request to the onedrive with accessToken I get 403

Comment: The 403 error means the following: 
Authorization failed. For example, the user does not have permission to access the resource. Are you sure you have access to this folder using the browser ?

Comment: Here is the ref. for all http status codes : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645548.aspx . Also, can you use Fiddler to check out what is being sent and what is the returned json object. let me know.

Comment: Yes I saw it before, but I don't know why the request return always 403, and when I used Fiddler tool he return me same 403 code, I don't know what is wrong. I follow documentation step by step

Comment: please post the request and the response so i will fix it for you!

Comment: Hi Mostafa. I make a log for request and response maybe this can help you. You can find here http://pastebin.com/R12VBwVD. I make a log for every service. But for onedrive business api we need only https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/me/.
Thank you so much, I really appreciated

Comment: Do the following: access the o365 sandbox api in this url: https://apisandbox.msdn.microsoft.com/ , then login with your o365 creds. and run the get files sample. make sure it executes and then your code should be following the same html sample code. let me know how it goes.

Comment: On apisandbox.msdn.microsoft.com I get the file, but when i try to connect from my script, again is 403. I don`t what happened there :(

Comment: You can grab the same code and run it from your machine, it should work. if it works this means your code is missing something. just try to run the code from your local box using html code so you have a working code to follow.

Comment: It's a bug http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32144097/onedrive-for-business-api-item-file-download-content-401/32344521#32344521, I hope they can fix